# Put value in datatable group by month

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, group-by

I have this datatable in c#

```
 Date    Employee Job1   Job2     Job3
1/1/2012    a    1      1          1 
1/1/2012    b    2      2          2
1/1/2012    c    2      1          4
1/1/2012    d    4      2          1
1/2/2012    a    3      2          5
1/2/2012    b    2      2          2
1/2/2012    c    3      3          3
1/2/2012    d    1      1          1
1/3/2012    a    5      5          5
1/3/2012    b    2      2          6
1/3/2012    c    1      1          1
1/3/2012    d    2      3          4
2/1/2012    a    2      2.5        2
2/1/2012    b    5      5          2
2/1/2012    c    2      2          2
2/2/2012    a    3      3          3
2/2/2012    b    2      3          3
3/1/2012    a    4      4          11
3/5/2012    a    14     42.5       15
3/6/2012    a    21     12.143     22
3/8/2012    a    8.9    45         27
3/8/2012    b    4.4    25         31
```

I want to loop through the values monthwise such that i can store the value in a datatable and will do the other calculation with that. Here with this example it will have three datatable, first with january values, another one with feb and last one with march rows. How can this be done by Linq. Please suggest the Linq syntax which will group the results month wise.

```
var monthEmpGroups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(r => new
                {                   
                    Year = DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DATE")).Year,
                    Month = DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DATE")).Month.ToString()
                })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Month);

var dtf = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
foreach (var empGroup in monthEmpGroups)
{
    int month = int.Parse(empGroup.Key);
    string colName = dtf.GetMonthName(month);
    // Here i want to get all the rows where month is colName (i.e.january, feb, march)
}
```

Please suggest if there is other way around to get the values month wise using LINQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move getting items for every group into `monthEmpGroups` query:

```
var monthEmpGroups = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      let month = DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("DATE")).Month
                      group r by month into g
                      select new { Month = g.Key, Items = g.ToList() });
```

With that you can easily get desired results:

```
var dtf = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;

foreach (var empGroup in monthEmpGroups)
{
    int month = empGroup.Month;
    string colName = dtf.GetMonthName(month);
    List<DataRow> items = empGroup.Items;
}
```